# Android JUnit Testing Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, gui-testing

I am trying to perform a simple test on my class just to test that the correct next activity is started when a button is pressed.

In my class the a different activity is started depending on whether the user is the manager or any other user.

This is the code in my test class:

```
package com.footballadmin.ssfc.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.footballadmin.ssfc.ApplicationMenu;
import com.footballadmin.ssfc.Calendar;
import com.footballadmin.ssfc.ManagerMenu;
import com.footballadmin.ssfc.R;

public class CalendarTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Calendar> {

    private ImageView menu;
    private Calendar mActivity;
    private String userEmail, managerEmail;



public CalendarTest() {
        super("com.footballadmin.ssfc.test", Calendar.class);
    }


    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = getActivity();
        userEmail = "test@test.com";
        managerEmail = "cstewart@gmail.com";
        menu = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.calendar_menu_icon);
    }

    public void testPreConditions() {
        assertTrue (menu != null);
    }

    //test Menu Button for manager
        @Test
        public void testCalendarMenuButtonIfUserIsManager() {

            mActivity.currentUserEmail = managerEmail;
            ActivityMonitor activityMonitor =   getInstrumentation().addMonitor(ManagerMenu.class.getName(), null, false);

            mActivity = getActivity();
            menu = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.calendar_menu_icon);

            mActivity.runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                            menu.requestFocus();
                            menu.performClick();

                        }

                    });

            Activity nextActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 15);
            assertNotNull(nextActivity);
            nextActivity.finish();              

        }


        //testMenuButton for general user
        @Test
        public void testCalendarMenuButtonIfUserIsUser() {

            mActivity.currentUserEmail = userEmail;
            ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(ApplicationMenu.class.getName(), null, false);

            mActivity = getActivity();
            menu = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.calendar_menu_icon);

            mActivity.runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                            menu.requestFocus();
                            menu.performClick();

                        }
                    });

            Activity nextActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 15);
            assertNotNull(nextActivity);
            nextActivity .finish();


        }

        //STUB test if news is populated
        @Test
        public void testCalendarIsPopulated(){

        }

}
```

And the following is my code in the corresponding class (only including relevant code to tests):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_menu_icon);

    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(final View view) {

          //Receiving user from shared preferences
           final SharedPreferences sharedPref =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Calendar.this);
           currentUserEmail = sharedPref.getString("email", "anon");
            Log.d("CurrentUser", currentUserEmail);

                if(currentUserEmail.equals(Constants.MANAGER_EMAIL))
                {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ManagerMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                              ApplicationMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });


}
```

When I run this test class I am getting the following in LogCat:

```
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066): Activity com.footballadmin.ssfc.Calendar has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4182e0d0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.footballadmin.ssfc.Calendar has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4182e0d0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at com.footballadmin.ssfc.Calendar$LoadCalendar.onPreExecute(Calendar.java:175)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at com.footballadmin.ssfc.Calendar.onResume(Calendar.java:97)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-31 06:48:58.381: E/WindowManager(1066):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And the following in the JUnit window:

    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at     com.footballadmin.ssfc.test.CalendarTest.testCalendarMenuButtonIfUserIsManager(CalendarTest.java:61)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
    at   android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Any thoughts on what my problem may be?

Many thanks!